# Conditions for running a function again

Tags: vb.net, console-application

This is my code

```
Sub Main()

    process()

    Console.WriteLine("Ulangi Pencarian? (Y/N)?")
    strUlangi = Console.ReadLine()

    'conditions for searching
    If strUlangi.ToUpper = "Y" Then

        Console.WriteLine()
        process()
        Console.WriteLine()

    Else

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write("Press any key to exit")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End If

  End Sub

 Sub process()

    Console.WriteLine("Masukan Kode Mahasiswa : ")
    decKodeMhs = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Masukan Kode Matakuliah : ")
    decKodeMatkul = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pencarian : ")
    Console.WriteLine("Nilai Mahasiswa A.N " & strNamaMhs(decKodeMhs) & " untuk Matakuliah " & StrNamaMatkul(decKodeMatkul) & " adalah " & intNilaiMhs(decKodeMhs, decKodeMatkul))
    Console.WriteLine()

 End Sub
```

I want to if i input the "Y" ,  function of process will be run again. Its was work, but when i input the variable of decKodeMatkul, the application is exit. Why is it?? Please somebody tell me

Comment: If you want to do something multiple times then you should be using a loop.  If you want to keep doing something while a condition is true or until a condition is true then you should use a `Do` or `While` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put the 
        `Console.ReadKey()`
At the end of the code.

```
Sub Main()

    process()
    Console.WriteLine("Ulangi Pencarian? (Y/N)?")
    strUlangi = Console.ReadLine()
    'conditions for searching
    If strUlangi.ToUpper = "Y" Then
        Console.WriteLine()
        process()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write("Press any key to exit")
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Sub process()
    Console.WriteLine("Masukan Kode Mahasiswa : ")
    decKodeMhs = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Masukan Kode Matakuliah : ")
    decKodeMatkul = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Hasil Pencarian : ")
    Console.WriteLine("Nilai Mahasiswa A.N " & strNamaMhs(decKodeMhs) & " untuk Matakuliah " & StrNamaMatkul(decKodeMatkul) & " adalah " & intNilaiMhs(decKodeMhs, decKodeMatkul))
    Console.WriteLine()

End Sub
```

Your process() actually do work, but it excute too fast then close, so you think that it just close.

Comment: as  jmcilhinney mention above, you should put it in a loop

Comment: like while 1 ... if...  excute() else return 0...  i dont remember the syntax but, thats the way to go